# Python list subclass with O(1) prepend / How to get bisect to work with reverse sorted list

Tags: python, binary-search, deque

For a particular problem, I need to have a list that:

1. supports `O(1)` prepend, and
2. that I can call [`bisect.bisect_left`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/bisect.html?highlight=bisect#bisect.bisect_left) on, which means the list must be sorted.

Prepending to a list via `list.insert(0, item)` is `O(N)`; however, `O(1)` prepend can be emulated by maintaining the list in reverse order in which case `list.append` emulates `O(1)` `prepend`. This would work, except that `bisect_left` only works for sorted input, not reverse sorted input. Other functions, like `min`, allow for reverse sorted order input (or input of arbitrary ordering) with their `key` argument; unfortunately, `bisect_left` does not have a `key` argument for performance reasons.

I have a workaround which I would like reviewed. It's a class that subclasses `list`. The class stores the list in reverse order so that prepend can be implemented via `O(1)` `append`, but overrides `__getitem__` and other methods so that from the outside (including from `bisect_left`'s view), it looks like the list is in normal order. This way, the list can be used by `bisect_left` and other functions that only work on sorted order input, and not on reverse sorted order input. The only indication that I have found so far that the list is in reverse is if you `print` it:

```
class PrependableList(list):
    '''List with O(1) "prepend". (appending is O(N))'''
    def __init__(self, l):
        super().__init__(reversed(l))
        
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        N = len(self)
        index = N - 1 - index
        return super().__getitem__(index)
    
    def __setitem__(self, index, item):
        N = len(self)
        index = N - 1 - index
        return super().__setitem__(index, item)
    
    def __iter__(self):
        return reversed(self)
    
    def prepend(self, item):
        super().append(item)
    
    # Are there any other `list` methods that I should override?

from bisect import bisect_left

nums = PrependableList([5,10,15,20])
nums.prepend(0)

print(nums) # [20, 15, 10, 5, 0] # <- how to make this print `[0, 5, 10, 15, 20]` instead?

for i in range(len(nums)):
    print(nums[i]) # uses __getitem__
# prints:
# 0
# 5
# 10
# 15
# 20

for num in nums: # uses __iter__
    print(num)
# prints:
# 0
# 5
# 10
# 15
# 20

# `bisect_left` works!
for num in range(0, 55):
    print(f'{num}: {bisect_left(nums, num)}') # uses __getitem__
# prints:
# 0: 0
# 1: 1
# 2: 1
# 3: 1
# 4: 1
# 5: 1
# 6: 2
# 7: 2
# 8: 2
# 9: 2
# 10: 2
# 11: 3
# 12: 3
# 13: 3
# 14: 3
# 15: 3
# 16: 4
# 17: 4
# 18: 4
# 19: 4
# 20: 4
# 21: 5
# 22: 5
# 23: 5
# 24: 5
# 25: 5
# 26: 5
# 27: 5
# 28: 5
# 29: 5
# 30: 5
# 31: 5
# 32: 5
# 33: 5
# 34: 5
# 35: 5
# 36: 5
# 37: 5
# 38: 5
# 39: 5
# 40: 5
# 41: 5
# 42: 5
# 43: 5
# 44: 5
# 45: 5
# 46: 5
# 47: 5
# 48: 5
# 49: 5
# 50: 5
# 51: 5
# 52: 5
# 53: 5
# 54: 5
```

Should just use a `deque`?

Comment: What python version do you use? From the bisect docs : "Changed in version 3.10: Added the key parameter."

Comment: @kubatucka I'm using 3.8. That's good news, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should just use a `deque`?

No. Unless you're ok with `bisect_left` taking O(n log n) instead of O(log n).

Your class doesn't support negative indexes, like lists normally do. Not saying you should add that (up to you, doesn't sound like you need it), but you can take advantage of lists supporting it to simplify your methods:

```
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return super().__getitem__(~index)
    
    def __setitem__(self, index, item):
        return super().__setitem__(~index, item)
```

Benchmark of `bisect_left` searching the middle value of a list, deque or PrependableList of a million elements:

```
  0.41 μs  bisect_left(lst, middle)
751.68 μs  bisect_left(deq, middle)
  5.77 μs  bisect_left(ppl, middle)
```

Benchmark code ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVFBasMwELzrFXsJkoJJnARCKeSYWw@9l2KSaJ0KZFmV5NJe@rK@oV9yV5aTGALVQbAzo9ndkfuKb63dPDjf97VvG4i6QR1BN671cawYCxg7BzvgnLNBdmqNwVPUrQ0XrcL3DjN71IHIC5GrymBNTidzCAGePTq06nA0@KRDFIYu@ciAjsIaqkpbHatKBDR1AWak0gmdQy/k4irx@IE@oBJGyonBGaOO2Fw9tFX4OfHxtJG3E7vbg@@sZczSxqsS5nPYskYrZZAAC8slrJkJkYo0t/AHe0ZhqT1FQOAQhCCBZM4ZAu62TVSKku2JfRlm4pOUkqCA3FHy4p6nDv/y1HbKvzJWtx4qCgHysJsxiQRjgve3ZNJe@d8FFjD8fAG2a47od6uyLOVV6by2UfDZdrGu4fcnAIcZiAhzWOFGFoBZmmWy7/8A)):

```
from timeit import timeit

setup = '''
from collections import deque
from bisect import bisect_left

class PrependableList(list):
    def __init__(self, l):
        super().__init__(reversed(l))
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return super().__getitem__(~index)

n = 10 ** 6
middle = n // 2
lst = list(range(n))
deq = deque(lst)
ppl = PrependableList(lst)
'''

E = [
    'bisect_left(lst, middle)',
    'bisect_left(deq, middle)',
    'bisect_left(ppl, middle)',
]

for _ in range(3):
    for e in E:
        t = timeit(e, setup, number=1000)
        print('%6.2f μs ' % (t * 1e3), e)
    print()
```

Comment: Thanks! `~x == -x - 1`, so I see how `~index` works perfectly for reverse indexing. It's a cool trick! Thanks for the benchmark! Why does `bisect_left` take `O(n log n)` on `deque`? Is it because `deque` is implemented as a (doubly) linked list, therefore `deque.__getitem__` is `O(n)`?

Comment: @joseville Yes, O(n) for that, and it gets called log n times.

Answer (score 1):

> Should I just use a `deque`?

Maybe, it depends on what exactly you're trying to do, but probably not - as dont talk just code pointed out, `deque` does not offer efficient access to elements near the middle, which is very much not great for binary search. Which is unfortunate, since this approach does come with a very real risk of missing pieces of functionality, especially if the base `list` class gets updated in future

Though the `help` built-in function can help avoid that by providing a list of known methods of a class

> `# Are there any other list methods that I should override?`

Well, there are several non-overridden methods which behave in unexpected ways

- While `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` do the right thing, `__delitem__` deletes the wrong element
- As does `pop`, `insert` and `index` get indexes wrong
- Likewise, `append` and `extend` don't append elements but prepend them instead
- `__reversed__` returns the same result as `__iter__`, which is probably not a good idea
- `sort` effectively sorts in reverse order
- `__add__` places the lists in the wrong order - `[1,2] + [3,4] == [1,2,3,4]`, but `PrependableList([1,2]) + PrependableList([3,4]) == PrependableList([3,4,1,2])`. `__iadd__` has the same problem
- You yourself noted that the list doesn't get printed in the expected manner - that's because `__repr__` isn't overridden

And finally, the current implementations of `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` don't support slices - `PrependableList([1,2,3,4,5])[1:3]` raises a `TypeError`

Comment: A deque turns the binary search from O(log n) into O(n log n). I don't think that's a good idea.

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode That's a good point which I completely overlooked, thanks for pointing it out

Comment: @SaraJ thanks, `help(list)` helps! I think I have two options: 1) override the methods mentioned, so that they do the right thing; or 2) Make the `PrependableList` class "private", so that it can only be used within the file/module it is defined in and I have total control over how it's used. #2 is viable because I only plan to use `PrependableList` within a single module. A StackOverflow post says that naming a class with a singe leading underscore will prevent it from being imported in a `from <module> import *` statement, so that seems like a sensible solution (although it has caveats).

Comment: With option #2 of my previous comment, would it also make sense to nest `PrependableList` within the sole class that uses it? Or fine to keep them as seperate classes of the same file/module?